# Regarding Mean Squared Error: I don't seem to understand this question

Tags: mean

I'm doing some statistics related stuff to get my level back at what it was back in the days of university. I just can't seem to get my head around the following question:

How does the Mean Squared Error penalizes small and large deviations from the true value?

I don't know whether I don't understand it because I don't understand the question or whatsoever, but I just don't see the answer.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you are referring to a regression problem where you are applying OLS then you are trying to minimize the mean square error. In so doing suppose most points fit closely to a line and one or a few points would have a large deviation from that line the fitted least squares line would be forced to move closer to these points while at the same time moving away from the other points in order that the total sum of squared error is minimized.

Answer (score 4):

Using squared errors, compared to absolute errors, gives more weight to large deviations. Imagine you have:

- 9 times an error or 1
- 1 time an error of 10

Mean absolute error is 1.9. (Root) Mean square error is 3.3. (Root) Mean square error is more influenced by the large error.

You can have a look at [the comparisons of various means](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality).

The consequence in ML (for example), is that using a squared error function tends to generate a model that makes a lot of rather small errors, while a absolute error function tends to generate a model with (competitively) a few large errors and many very small errors.